# "Instante eterno", ¿cuál es la figura?

Tags: palabras-raras, humor

Tengo estos pares que, por su significado, no pueden estar juntos, pero que por un juego de palabras tienen algún sentido figurado o son humorísticos.

Pero no puedo recordar (o nunca he sabido) su nombre. He pensado en ironía, paradoja, absurdo, pero sé que tiene que haber una palabra mejor...

> urbanismo gitano
>
> pobre rico
>
> inteligencia militar
>
> instante eterno

¿Cómo se llama este juego de palabras?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creo que el término que buscas es **oxímoron**.

> El oxímoron (del griego ὀξύμωρον, oxymoron, en latín *contradictio in terminis*), dentro de las figuras literarias en retórica, es una figura lógica que consiste en usar dos conceptos de significado opuesto en una sola expresión, que genera un tercer concepto.

Ese *tercer concepto* es metafórico, resultado del "absurdo" o imposible de la unión de los dos opuestos. A veces es humorístico y otras aumenta la fuerza expresiva.

- Clamoroso silencio (o silencio ensordecedor)
- Instante eterno
- Hielo abrasador
- Realidad virtual

entran dentro de esta categoría ([Ver más ejemplos de oxímoron](http://www.retoricas.com/2009/06/4-ejemplos-de-oximoron.html)).

No creo que "Inteligencia militar" sea realmente un oxímoron, ni que las dos palabras juntas tengan significados opuestos o humorísticos, aunque le puedes dar esta última connotación, siempre en el contexto de que el ejército no puedo hacer nada bueno o inteligente.

El oxímoron no tiene porqué ser sólo dos palabras:

- ángeles del infierno
- pequeño gran hombre
- ir a ningún sitio
- sí pero no.
- secreto a voces
- lleno de vacíos

Comment: OK, era la palabra, muchas gracias por la velocidad. Ahora googleamos y nos iluminamos, hay mucho material. Estoy trabajando en un ensayo sobre el humor con otras personas, y la "inteligencia militar" nos pareció muy graciosa como supuesta contradicción (pasando por alto susceptibilidades, por supuesto). En realidad se escapa un poco del concepto, como indicas.

Comment: Yo he dado con la definición gracias a dos que recordaba de un anuncio de la tele: clamoroso silencio (aparecía una procesión de Semana Santa) y doloroso placer (aparecían unos zapatos de tacón alto). Una vez que di con el nombre de la figura, es cierto que salen [ejemplos a patadas](http://www.oximoron.com/lista-oximoron.html). En esa lista está "ejército pacificador", por si quieres sustituir inteligencia militar.

Comment: ¡Un sitio entero para esta cosa! Iba a decir "¡santo dios!" pero queda mejor "santos demonios"... Muchas gracias por el link, está estupendo.