# Invitacion forzosa

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, oxímoron

¿Cómo se le llama a una invitación cuando es obligatoria?

O sea, mi jefe me envió una invitación a la fiesta de fin de año, pero luego manda un correo donde dice que la asistencia es obligatoria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diría que no es una invitación, sino una **convocatoria** dentro de la empresa. La empresa lo puede llamar de esta manera debido a la naturaleza del evento (una cena o una fiesta), pero si es de asistencia obligatoria no es una invitación sino una convocatoria o solicitud para un acto de empresa.

**Invitación forzosa** es en sí mismo casi un [oxímoron](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10265/5481), pero la RAE acoge como primera acepción de *invitar*:

> Llamar a alguien para un convite o para asistir a algún acto

y no dice nada acerca de la posibilidad de ignorar la llamada del recipiente.

Es como cuando ofreces a otra persona "de voluntario".

Answer (score 3):

En Chile a un llamado que no se puede rechazar le decimos **citación**.

Comment: Interesante! En España usamos _citación_, pero casi siempre en un contexto jurídico. Desde luego no rechazas una citación, porque suele venir de un juez, la policía o autoridades similares... Ese contexto es el que le da la connotación de "irrechazable". No sé si la usaríamos para este contexto (me han citado o he recibido una citación para una cena de empresa) pero la verdad es que la analogía es adecuada.