# ¿Hay alguna palabra o término en español para "umbrella term"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

"Umbrella term" es una palabra que abarca un montón de significados distintos. ¿Existe un término o palabra para referirse a algo así en español?

Comment: umbrella term for what?? In English, it is always specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Español existe el concepto como ["término global"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A9rmino_global)

> Un **término global** o **denominación general** (también conocido con la expresión **término paraguas**), es una palabra que designa a un conjunto o agrupación de conceptos relacionados. Los términos globales se conocen técnicamente como **hiperónimos<sup>1</sup>**.
>
> Por ejemplo, la *criptología* es un término que engloba la criptografía y el *criptoanálisis*, entre otros campos.

Existe también "*organización paraguas*" puede ser una organización que es un órgano de coordinación y representación de una serie de órganos separados más pequeños.

---

<sup>1. En semántica lingüística, se denomina *hiperónimo* a aquel término general que puede ser utilizado para referirse a la realidad nombrada por un término más específico. Por ejemplo, ser vivo es hiperónimo para los términos planta y animal (que son a su vez *hipónimos*).</sup>

Comment: Que hay del caso en que una palabra agrupa muchos términos no relacionados. Porque si bien estas palabras no deberían existir, existen ya sea por ignorancia acerca de la naturaleza de las cosas, o porque se crean a propósito para manipular la opinión pública a través del lenguaje. Existe una palabra así? "Umbrella term" no tiene una connotación de palabras relacionadas o no relacionadas, (creo), como sería término global o hiperónimo. Dejo abierto el topic un tiempo más a ver si veo otra respuesta que diga algo sobre esto, sino acepto esta.

Comment: @Pablo. Lo que planteas en tu comentario se refiere probablemente a las [palabras comodín](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Palabra_comod%C3%ADn), pero eso no corresponde a los "umbrella term". La respuesta de Diego es correcta.

Comment: [Umbrella term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrella_term) is "a word or phrase that covers a broad interval or set of functions or items that all fall under a single common category."

Comment: Bueno me convenciste acerca de la traducción de umbrella term Diego. Pero sigo buscando una palabra en español que haga referencia a varios términos contradictorios

Comment: @Pablo, si son contradictorios  tenemos por ejemplo el [oximoron](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10265/5481), pero creo que no es tampoco lo que buscas... Si no son palabras comodín, como sugiere Rodrigo, creo que no vendría mal formular una nueva pregunta, para palabras que abarquen "conceptos relacionados - o no - por ciertas cualidades".

Comment: @Pablo Sería de utilidad si tuvieras algún ejemplo de _umbrella term_ que abarque significados contradictorios.

Comment: @Pablo, ¿se podría decir que estos términos diversos comparten un *tema* común?  Si no, ¿qué es lo que comparten?

Comment: por ejemplo muchos neologismos (sin entrar en detalles para no entrar en temas muy controversiales y que irritan a mucha gente) tienen más de un significado, muchas veces contradictorios, y se usan para manipular la forma de pensar de la gente "este atributo/caracteristica/propiedad quiere decir tambien esta otra cosa o conlleva esta otra cosa como consecuencia"<--- usualmente esas premisas que esconden muchos neologismos son falsas, y hacen que la palabra con la caracteristica  "x" y significado "x", pase a tener tambien otro significado "y" en forma de premisa (premisa que es falsa)

Answer (score 0):

También se puede utilizar «término aglutinante»:

> Gran parte del frente opositor está representado por ese mundo variopinto que podemos englobar bajo un término aglutinante: conservadurismo.

> La violencia contra la mujer es un término aglutinante de todos los tipos de violencia ejercida contra este grupo de personas […]

> Transgénero es un término aglutinante (incluye una amplia variedad de identidades) que reúne a personas cuya identidad de género y/o expresión de género difiere de lo que típicamente es asociado con el sexo que se les asignó en su nacimiento.

Ejemplos tomados de Google.

Si me toca traducir algún texto que contenga *umbrella term*, también opto por hacer una redacción explicativa, con frases como «denominación amplia» o «La expresión X abarca Y y Z». Como ves, no es una frase que tenga tanto asentamiento (por no ser más que un «hipernónimo» de toda la vida; no es un concepto novedoso ni siquiera en inglés), y entre pares de idiomas no siempre existe un equivalente fraseológico o terminológico en ambas direcciones.